# Toggling multiple toolbars on/off in QGIS

Tags: qgis, toolbar

In QGIS 3.12, from the View menu I go to Toolbars to toggle several of them on/off.  However, when I toggle one (either way) I'm returned immediately to the previous screen.  I've tried holding down the Control key but this action is ignored. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4):

When toggling on or off a Toolbar from the View --- > Toolbars will automatically close the menu after clicking. A quicker way to add/remove toolbars or panel is to click on the tool bars and a context menu will open with the tools/panels you want to toggle.

[image]

I do not know of any way to toggle on/off many at the same time.

You could also remove multiple toolbars using PyQGIS,the information is available [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/cheat_sheet.html?highlight=toolbars#toolbars)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this issue is related to QGIS itself, but it's related to PyQt. It has been always like that. Because the menus ("View > Toolbars" and the right click context menus) are only menus and a menu normally disappears after clicking its any item. Though, in this case, one can find it tedious.

I have added a [feature request for this issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34635). However, this is not an important issue among others.

Comment: Your feature request is worthwhile.  It is such a standrad approach to use the Control key in Windows to multi-select that it is expected universally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hotkey *Ctrl+Tab* (Toggle Panel Visibility) to turn on/off all the panels at the same time.